# TypeError: expressValidator is not a function How do i fix this Error?

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

What should I do to fix this expressValidator error?

below is the error [image][image] which occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option one: you can downgrade your `express-validator` package version to `5.3.0`.

Run these commands:

`npm uninstall express-validator`

`npm install express-validator@5.3.0`

Second option you have is to follow the instructions by the official documentations by express-validator:[Migration from v5 to v6](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/migration-v5-to-v6.html)